# Exporting matrices in Ansys Fluent

Tags: fluent, ansys

I want to export the matrix of the temperatures of a tube in ansys fluent.

The rows of the matrix should be times of the flow of the fluid from the start time of the simulation to the finishing time, and the columns of the matrix should be the temperature of the fluid at multiple points of the tube. How can I export this kind of matrix to Ansys Fluent? I have tested "Export during calculation" and "Austosave", but I couldn't get the matrix.